# Notification in tampermonkey / Javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, notifications

I have a facebook group where i want to get a notification on my desktop when there is a new post. To do this, i downloaded "Page refresh" for chrome, and that will update the page every set interval. Then i downloaded tampermonkey, to make the userscript.

I made a userscript that worked fine, just posting an alert on the page when a there is a new post in the group (checking in 30seconds intervals if anything have been posted within the last 30seconds). So the last part of the code should work, but when i add the "notifyMe" method, it stops working..

But as i wanted to get a notification even if im doing work in my browser, i found the Notification posibility. But i cant get it to work. Here is my code:

```
jsfiddle.net/x4bW6/
```

Is it because tampermonkey can not run notifications? Because notifications worked just fine for me, when i tested it where i found the code: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/notification

Comment: the first notification, the part where you ask for permission, must be fired as a result of a user interaction event. that is to say you have to call the notification function from an onclick() event, not just from some javascript code. once you grant permission, tampermonkey itself can issue desktop notifications without user interaction. the easiest way to get it working for yourself is to just append a <button> to <body >that calls the code you already have, notifyMe(), click it, and choose yes in the "yellow bar warning".

Comment: You also might want to take a look at TM's GM_notification function. http://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php